# Combine 360 HDR with video background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass, hdri

[image]
I have a scene with some Glass BSDF Text and a rendered video as background. 
Because the video is not in 360°, I'd like to add a HDRi Image as Environment, but still keep the video as background to get the right refraction.
Any idea on how to combine the two?

My World Shader as of now:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a side note, I would use the *Background BSDF* for the worlds background.

You can use the [Texture Coordinate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html)s **Window** socket (which you are using already) to determine, wether a light ray is inside the cameras view or outside.

[image: result]

Separate the **Window** sockets output into its channels. This will result in X, Y and Z coordinates from the camera view window. We are interested in the X and Y values which are inbetween of `[0, 1]`. We can filter them out with the *Greater than* and *Less than* nodes.

[image: node setup]

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by adding a plane, and positioning it in front of the camera, behind your text.  Then, add an emission material to the plane, and adding your movie texture to the emission color.  next you can add an HDR to the world.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: This might not work if the camera moves during the animation.